# Personal property insurance + travelling insurance + accident insurance + health insurance

Tags: insurance, norway, finland, estonia

The definitions of the specific terms of the insurances differ among different companies.
Also, some insurances like Travel Insurance is substitute of Property Insurance during certain specific of times.
It is important to take this into account because I am travelling every third week to Norway, which means that I can take advantage of Travelling Insurance as Property Insurance.
Therefore, **I will cover insurances generally**, calling them by some logic names, but note that the definition and rules are important to check out for each insurance. I am  using some terms found at [Bogleheads.org](http://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Insurance#Risks_to_insure).

Some essential facts which makes the problem manageable.

- I want to get insurances that are **fixed to some index**.
- I want to get insurances and **no deductible** such that I do not need to pay penalties in the case of accident if possible.
- I want to get the **medical practice in Finland or Norway**. This is an important fact, since some insurances are only valid in the country where you bought them, although the travelling insurance substitutes it a little, but not completely. In Finland, the medical practice is cheaper than in Norway. So it is probable that I get **my health insurance from Finland**. I want to take advantage of the lower price level in Finland, since the quality of services between Finland and Norway is about the same.
- I am currently registered to live in Norway. I also spend less than half a year in Finland. This means that I cannot get for instance YoungLiving insurance of Tryg in Finland. However, some other Finnish insurance companies like [Tapiola](http://www.tapiola.fi/www/Yksityisasiakkaat/Vakuutukset/etusivu.htm) and [Aktia](http://www.aktia.fi/vakuutukset) allow me to sell me insurances. There are differences where you can get the service provided by the insurance. For instance, Aktia considers Finland and Sweden together as "homeland", while Tapiola not. So no benefit for me about Aktia thinking. It would be useful if whole Nordic countries would be considered as a homeland for me. **Please, cover the insurance cover differences between countries below if you know about the topic.**
- I am in Estonia and Finland the rest of the year mostly.
- I can get personal property insurance only for the things in my rented apartment in Estonia. However, because I am travelling every third week to Norway, I can use Norwegian Travel Insurance as property insurance in Estonia. Nevertheless, I think that the travel insurance does not cover for instance the lost of my bicycle in Estonia. **TODO check this out.**

## Norway, Tryg insurance

The insurance, [YoungLiving More Stuff Tryg](http://www.tryg.no/odpdf?vilkNr=05PPK13503&vilk=YoungLiving-Stuff-Dekningsvilkaar-More), costs in Norway 340 euros.
It covers in the case of accident:

- Travel insurance - 90 days.
- Accident insurance - max 68000 euros if get handicapped like lose a hand.
- Home insurance in Norway - max 68000 euros per accident.
- Sport insurance - max 6800 euros for one time and 15 600 euros for sport accident. Bike insurance max 2000 euros.
- Computer, PC, telefon, videocamera etc insurance max 2000 euros
- Insurance "løsørekasko i hjemmet" if you break something by yourself at your home by accident max 13500 euros.
- I pay 136 euros for any incidence that happens if you want to get insurance money.

I live in hostels in Norway so I think I do not need the home insurance.
However, the packet price is cheaper than only taking a few insurances for young.

## Estonia, If insurance

In Estonia, I can only get protection because of theft at the price of 25 euros per year for my equipments at my home.
I can also get travelling insurance from there that covers only medication things.

## Finland, Tryg

[Tryg](http://www.tryg.fi/fi/henkiloasiakkaat/youngliving/tuotetiedot/) is in Finland too, but they do not give it to me because I am less than half a year there.
The price of the similar insurance than in Norway would be about 1/3 of the price than in Norway and lower penalty, (85 < 136) in the case of accident.
However, all the max levels are about one third of those in Norway.

---

For people living permanently in Norway, I have heard that

- **Tryg YoungLiving package = Base Travel and Accident + More Travel + More Sport + Base Stuff + More Stuff** (lower deduces). It is the most sold in Norway for youths and best price-quality index. This package however has Home insurance for home in Norway which I do not need at the moment.

So I want

- Health insurance with good cover: surgery, drugs, plastic surgery in accident, special doctor, ... and with no deductible.
- Travel insurance with at least 45 days. Tryg.no offers 90 days by *More Travel*.
- Sport insurance - if I cycle against a car and break someone's car, for instance. No extreme sport.
- Property insurance for my stuff at my home in Estonia. TODO probably Tryg's Travel insurance covers this. Not sure if my bike covered.
- Accident insurance, for instance in the case of paralysis

**Which combination of insurances would you recommend for me in different countries?**

My current plan is

- Health insurance - Tapiola Finland or Aktia Finland
- Travel insurance - Tryg Norway
- Accident insurance - Tryg Norway
- Probaly, Sport insurance - Tryg Norway
- Property insurance, If Estonia - TODO must check if Tryg Norway Travel Insurance cover the lost of my bike in Estonia for instance
- If Norway products TODO check them.

I selected some products from Norway because they have better max limits.
However, I need to model this thing, if it is really needed.
Finnish products may be ok.

Comment: This is a good question.  I wish I had the regional knowledge to answer it.

Comment: What's the value of the possessions in your apartment that need insuring?

Comment: The value of the possessions in my apartment is 8000 euros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many factors that need to be taken into account.
I will now cover taxation, the coverage provided by the insurances and where you can use those services.

### Taxation benefits of insurances in Norway

I found the following piece of information about Travelling Insurance in Skatt.no where I am a member in Norway:

> Har arbeidsgiver fradragsrett for premiebetaling?
>
> Ja. Uansett om arbeidsgiver dekker en reiseforsikring på yrkesreise,
>   eller om det også er en del som skal behandles som lønn, vil
>   arbeidsgiver ha fradragsrett.

So my boss can make tax reduction in my loan for my travelling insurance which costs about 251 euros per year only, *Tryg Base Travel + More Travel*.

And the money which I get from this is not taxable, "ikke skattepliktig".

### Insurances in Norway

### Tryg.no Health insurance - Behandlingsforsikring

Health insurance
I can get with 999 NOK/year the following health insurance which is very good:

> Grunndekning - Garanti om innleggelse/behandling innen 21 virkedager -
>   Sykehusbehandling /operasjon - Spsialistbehandling utredning og
>   behandling - Medisiner - som inngår i behandlingen - Tekniske
>   hjelpemidler - etter operasjon - Gjennopptrening - etter innleggelse
>   og operasjon - Second Opinion - Tannbehandling - oppstått i
>   forbindelse med sykdom som behandles - Rus- og spilleavvenning -
>   behandling - Plastikkirugi - Reiseutgifter - nødvendige utgifter i
>   forbindelse med operasjon og behandling - 0ppholdsutgifter -
>   nødvendige utgifter i forbindelse med operasjon og behandling -
>   Reiseledsager - når dette er medisinsk nødvendig

paying 1341 NOK/year you get also more health care services

> FYSIKALSKE BEHANDLINGER - Fysioterapeut - Manuell terapeut -
>   Kiropraktor - Naprapat - Klassisk akupunktur 8 behandlingstimer per
>   rullerende år uavhengig av behandlingsform

and paying 1426 NOK you get also psychiatric services:

> Psykolog- og krisehjelp PSYKOLOG- OG KRISEHJELP - Psykolog - 10
>   behandlingstimer - Krisehjelp - 10 behandlingstimer

and you can use these services in

```
Norway
Sweden
Denmark
Finland
Germany
```

which is a very big plus for me, since I am going to work in those countries in the future.

Then, if you get many insurances from Tryg.no, you get things cheaper:
[image]

**Discussion.** The coverage where you can use these services is excellent, much better than provided by Finnish products such as Tapiola, If and Aktia. Please, see the terms of the insurance [here](http://www.tryg.no/odpdf?vilkNr=05UUL41702&vilk=Barn-og-ungdom-Ekstra-Behandlingsforsikring).
The price is fixed to an index which is a good thing.
The insurance is expiring only when you are 75 years old.
In Finland, the same upper limit is 64 years in many insurance companies.

Answer (score 2):

### Estonia

I went to ask questions in the insurance company store *[If](http://www.if.ee/)* in Estonia.
They provide only Medical Aid as *Travelling insurance*.

### **Medical insurance as "Travelling insurance" in Estonia - not insurance for property**

- in the Nordic countries, only once 60 days, price 36.64 e
- in the Europe, one year, max 45 at once, so many times as wanted, price 57.51 e

So this insurance is not for me, since I also want property insurance for those stuff such as tablet, laptop and e-reader that I am carrying with me.
Such a property insurance, the company *If* does not provide for travelling at reasonable prices.
If I understood the example of the seller right, the price of such insurances in Estonia starts at 1000 euros for me per year, because I can get better insurance with lower price from Norway.

### **Property insurance for the stuff at my home in Estonia**

The price is 39.73 euros for the property of 8000 euros at my home.
This should cover at least theft.

The penalty in the case of theft of one item seems to be from **12%** to **25%** depending on the type of the item and on the value of the item.

There does not seem to be any way to decrease the *penalty cost* by paying more the year-money.

No penalty if

- broken lock or stolen keys - covers the cost of broken locks or keys - no other property covered
- window broken - covers the cost of broken windown - no other property covered

The property insurance seems to be ok for the situations that happen in Estonia, since it is the only one which I can get, although not that good which you can get for your home in Norway.

Answer (score 1):

### European legislation and coming changes 2012-2014

There will be an European law in action which says that the price between different insurances cannot vary between two sexes.
This change affects prices in Finland and Estonia, but not in Norway that is not part of EU.

Some facts 19.12.2012

- The Health insurance is cheaper for men than women.
- The Accident insurance is more expensive for men than women.

So take your Health insurance this year, and your accident insurance after if you are a man and if you want your insurance in Finland or Estonia.

### Other change coming at the end of the year 2013

You can get your health care operation in any hospital you want in about a year from now.
This again means increases in insurance prices in those countries where those operations are cheap to do, like in Estonia.
It would also probably generally increase prices both in short and long term, since travelling costs increase.

Comment: It is very positive that things are getting more homogenous in the North 60° so less wasting time with endless products. Perhaps you could ask direct offers with demands -- and then find proper insurances -- I am afraid things are already changed after I finish my writing.

Answer (score 0):

I received today a call from the company.
So I add some pieces of information about their offer here.

### Finland

### [Lähivakuutus](http://www.lahivakuutus.fi/FI/Sivut/EtusivuLV.aspx) - Deductible

- Young Living insurance, similar to Tryg.fi - Price 85 euros/year.
- Health insurance - 100 euros/year. If you take it, you get 50% discount from Young Living insurance.

Cons

- You need to live in Finland more than half a year each year
- You need to be registered to live in Finland
- The insurances also apply to 64 years TODO check this.
- You can get Health service only in Finland. You need to play with Travelling insurance to get same benefits.